# coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found when rendering in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have this error since a long time but can't figure it out :

**Caught TypeError while rendering: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found**

It happens in admin when I try to add or modify on one of my models (display works fine)

This is the model:

```
class PS(models.Model):
    id_ps = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=True, blank=True)
    nom_du_site = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    rue_livraison = models.TextField(null=True)
    complement_adresse = models.TextField(null=True)
    code_postal_livraison = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    ville_livraison = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    pays_livraison = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    distributeur = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    tarif = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True)
    type_tarif = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    type_installation = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nom_du_site

    @property
    def pce(self):        
        try:
            return PCE.objects.filter(ps=self)[0]
        except IndexError:
            return
    #    
    def get_pce(self):
        from pce.models import PCE
        return PCE.objects.filter(ps=self).exclude(frequence='6M')
    #
    def get_pce_6m(self):
        from pce.models import PCE
        return PCE.objects.filter(ps=self,frequence='6M')
```

Any idea what am i doing wrong here?

**Traceback:**

```
    Environment:

    Request Method: GET
    Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8026/admin/ps/ps/add/
    Django Version: 1.2.5
    Python Version: 2.7.2
    Installed Applications:
    ['django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.sites',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'easy_thumbnails',
     'django_extensions',
     'contentadmin',
     'south',
     'sentry',
     'sentry.client',
     'indexer',
     'file_uploader',
     'paging',
     'pagination',
     'consommation',
     'ps',
     'pce',
     'profil',
     'analytics',
     'document']
    Installed Middleware:
    ('annoying.middlewares.StaticServe',
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
     'pagination.middleware.PaginationMiddleware')


    Template error:
    In template /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html, error at line 19
       Caught TypeError while rendering: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
       9 :             {% for field in line %}


       10 :                 <div{% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' %} class="field-box{% if not field.is_readonly and field.errors %} errors{% endif %}"{% endif %}>


       11 :                     {% if not line.fields|length_is:'1' and not field.is_readonly %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}


       12 :                     {% if field.is_checkbox %}


       13 :                         {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}


       14 :                     {% else %}


       15 :                         {{ field.label_tag }}


       16 :                         {% if field.is_readonly %}


       17 :                             <p>{{ field.contents }}</p>


       18 :                         {% else %}


       19 :                              {{ field.field }} 


       20 :                         {% endif %}


       21 :                     {% endif %}


       22 :                     {% if field.field.field.help_text %}


       23 :                         <p class="help">{{ field.field.field.help_text|safe }}</p>


       24 :                     {% endif %}


       25 :                 </div>


       26 :             {% endfor %}


       27 :         </div>


       28 :     {% endfor %}


       29 : </fieldset>


    Traceback:
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
      288.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      76.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
      78.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
      190.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
      21.             return decorator(bound_func)(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      76.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
      17.                 return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/transaction.py" in _commit_on_success
      299.                     res = func(*args, **kw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in add_view
      909.         return self.render_change_form(request, context, form_url=form_url, add=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in render_change_form
      692.         ], context, context_instance=context_instance)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render_to_response
      20.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
      186.     return t.render(context_instance)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
      173.             return self._render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in _render
      167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
      796.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
      72.             result = node.render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
      125.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in _render
      167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
      796.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
      72.             result = node.render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
      125.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in _render
      167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
      796.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
      72.             result = node.render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
      62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
      796.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
      72.             result = node.render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
      174.                 nodelist.append(node.render(context))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
      139.             return self.template.render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
      173.             return self._render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in _render
      167.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
      796.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
      72.             result = node.render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
      174.                 nodelist.append(node.render(context))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
      174.                 nodelist.append(node.render(context))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
      260.             return self.nodelist_false.render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
      796.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
      72.             result = node.render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
      260.             return self.nodelist_false.render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/__init__.py" in render
      796.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
      72.             result = node.render(context)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render
      91.             output = force_unicode(output)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_unicode
      66.                 s = unicode(s)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in __unicode__
      408.         return self.as_widget()
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in as_widget
      450.         return widget.render(name, data, attrs=attrs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py" in render
      247.         output = [self.widget.render(name, value, *args, **kwargs)]
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in render
      447.         options = self.render_options(choices, [value])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/widgets.py" in render_options
      464.         for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in __iter__
      898.                 yield self.choice(obj)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in choice
      904.         return (self.field.prepare_value(obj), self.field.label_from_instance(obj))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/forms/models.py" in label_from_instance
      955.         return smart_unicode(obj)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in smart_unicode
      39.     return force_unicode(s, encoding, strings_only, errors)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/encoding.py" in force_unicode
      66.                 s = unicode(s)

    Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/ps/ps/add/
    Exception Value: Caught TypeError while rendering: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found
```

Comment: why the lack of `from/import` and duplicate `from/import` all of the same module?

Comment: i see `{% for field in line %}`, what is `line`?

Comment: @rednaw Its In template /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html  So I dont know either

Comment: @KevinDTimm where is that? I dont get what you mean sorry

Comment: why are you doing `return unicode(self.nom_du_site)` anyway? why not just `return self.nom_du_site`? What's in that column anyway? Maybe it's something to do with that.

Comment: I have tried this to solve the problem but it didnt, my original is `return self.nom_du_site`

Comment: in get_pce and get_pce_6m you have `from pce.models import PCE` but earlier, you use `PCE.objects.filter` and you haven't imported PCE - it might just be redundant but it's odd

Comment: when I move it to the top I get an error in PCE model,it's because there are a lot of relations beteween all the models, And I dont think That would cause my current issue

Comment: That's a fairly old version of Django coupled with a fairly new Python version.  Any chance you can test with a newer version of Django?

Comment: No I can't,its the version of the production server

Comment: SOLVED : the error came from the data !

Answer (score 92, accepted):

This error happens when you have a `__unicode__` method that is a returning a field that is not entered. Any blank field is `None` and Python cannot convert `None`, so you get the error.

In your case, the problem most likely is with the `PCE` model's `__unicode__` method, specifically the field its returning.

You can prevent this by returning a default value:

```
def __unicode__(self):
   return self.some_field or u'None'
```

Comment: Incidentally (for those who may be bleary-eyed from a late night), it can also be caused by *not returning anything* in the `__unicode__`. :)

Comment: Even if your object's field seems fine on a Change page, you can have this when one of the related fields `__unicode__` returns None!

Comment: Or in python3 (Django 2.0) - def __str__(self): return unicode(self.some_field) or "" - I had some fields null and data were already in with filled data - so I could not delete them from admin - returning the default value did the trick...

Answer (score 14):

This error might occur when you return an object instead of a string in your `__unicode__` method. For example:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    . . . 
    name = models.CharField(...)


class Book(models.Model):
    . . .
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, ...)
    . . .
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.author  # <<<<<<<< this causes problems
```

To avoid this error you can cast the author instance to unicode:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    . . . 
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.author)  # <<<<<<<< this is OK
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was something else: the object I was saving should first have an id(e.g. save() should be called) before I could set any kind of relationship with it.

Answer (score 0):

The return value def __unicode __ should be similar to the return value of the related models (tables) for correct viewing of "some_field" in django admin panel.
You can also use:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.some_field
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the earlier function with the provided one. The simplest solution is:

```
def __unicode__(self):

    return unicode(self.nom_du_site)
```

Answer (score -5):

First, check that whatever you are returning via **unicode** is a String.

If it is not a string you can change it to a string like this (where self.id is an integer)

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return '%s' % self.id
```

following which, if it still doesn't work, restart your ./manage.py shell for the changes to take effect and try again. It should work.

Best Regards

Comment: No. Whatever you return via `__unicode__` must be a *unicode* object, not a bytestring. Use `unicode(self.id)` or, if you must, `u'%s' % self.id`. (It's true that in this case the answer will work because id is always going to be an integer, but answers should give the correct implementation not something that just happens to work by accident.)