# django - coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-models, django-templates

I am using python 2.7 & django 1.7.

I have a model that I want to return a field to be used in a template, however that field may be blank, which means that I receive this error when I attempt to place a condition statement to the return field.

Here is my code:

```
class ContactDetails(FillableModelWithLanguageVersion):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    contact_details_phone = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=30)
    contact_details_mobile_phone = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=30)
    contact_details_email_address = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=250)
    contact_details_linkedin_address = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=250)
    contact_details_facebook_address = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=250)
    contact_details_twitter_address = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=250)
    contact_details_timestamp_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    contact_details_timestamp_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return
        if self.contact_details_mobile_phone:
            truncatechars(self.contact_details_mobile_phone, 30)
        elif self.contact_details_phone:
            truncatechars(self.contact_details_phone, 30)
        ......
```

When I apply the if elif condition above, I receive the following error:

**coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found**

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16169035/coercing-to-unicode-need-string-or-buffer-nonetype-found-when-rendering-in-dja) and applied the suggested fixes, but this does not work for me. Here is an example of one attempt I have tried

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return
    if self.contact_details_mobile_phone:
        unicode(truncatechars(self.contact_details_mobile_phone, 30)) or u''
    elif self.contact_details_phone:
        unicode(truncatechars(self.contact_details_phone, 30)) or u''
    .....
```

I continue to get the same error message. I have checked the data and the data is good. I am wondering if I have misused the if elif condition syntax?

**Does anyone have a suggestion I could attempt?**

Comment: Your  `__unicode__` method returns None immediately, you need to move the return statement after your if/else clause.

Comment: facepalm! Yes that is embarrassing. Thanks for pointing out my stupid error. I was so focused on the condition I neglected the return!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You returned `None` from your function by doing just `return`. Your function just returned earlier before your `if else` code block executed(maybe you were a ruby developer or something but python doesn't work like that).

Comment: Thanks. I cannot believe how stupid that mistake was! It took someone else to see it.